# C# Calling Delegate Constructor With Missing Argument & No Default Values

Tags: c#, constructor, delegates

Here is some code that is creating a delegate:

```
    public Ticker()
    {
        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000.0);
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(SendTimeUpdates);
    }

    public void SendTimeUpdates(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        SendAlerts(false);
    }
```

However when I look at the definition of ElapsedEventHandler I see this:

```
public delegate void ElapsedEventHandler(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e);
```

In order to construct this object you need two values passed. However the preceding code gets away with passing a reference to a function that matches the signature.

I would think in order to create an instance of ElapsedEventHandler you would need to do this:

```
timer.Elapsed = new ElapsedEventHandler(mySender, eventArgs);
```

I don't see any overloaded constructors (or optional default values) which only take 1 argument but this code is valid, compiles, and works. Can you explain what is happening?

Comment: A delegate always wraps a method, it's when the delegate is later invoked that you pass in arguments for the parameters to that method. So the code is entirely correct. You wrap the `SendTimeUpdates` method in a delegate.

Comment: You can also write this as `new ElapsedEventHandler((sender , e) => SendTimeUpdates(sender, e));`. What you have right now is the short syntax for this, and it compiles because the method signature of `SendTimeUpdates` matches the delegate.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Interesting, I had used delegates before but I never connected the dots between the syntax and the concept you laid out. Thank you.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange Yes seeing the long form helps it make more sense as to what is going on. So the parameters are in fact the parameters that the invoked function needs to have. Thank you.